# Shuffle.js options error fix

Tags: javascript, shuffle

i'm using [shuffle.js](http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) for my current project. it works pretty well... the only this is, i am having a console error with default Override-able options.

my issue originates exactly at the `columnThreshold` option part. if i remove that line of code, my layout becomes unresponsive and messed up. but when i insert the line `columnThreshold: HAS_COMPUTED_STYLE ? 0.01 : 0.1,` , my layout becomes responsive but i get a console error and the effect of the `speed: 250` option is becomes useless... basically i can't control the shuffle speed...

the consol error states `Uncaught ReferenceError: HAS_COMPUTED_STYLE is not defined`. the documentation does not provide any information regarding the possible options for the `columnThreshold`. all i want is for the `columnThreshold` value to not affect the `speed` or other options value.

my entire code looks like this:

```js
// Overrideable options
Shuffle.options = {
  group: ALL_ITEMS, // Initial filter group.
  speed: 250, // Transition/animation speed (milliseconds).
  easing: 'ease-out', // CSS easing function to use.
  itemSelector: '', // e.g. '.picture-item'.
  sizer: null, // Sizer element. Use an element to determine the size of columns and gutters.
  gutterWidth: 0, // A static number or function that tells the plugin how wide the gutters between columns are (in pixels).
  columnWidth: 0, // A static number or function that returns a number which tells the plugin how wide the columns are (in pixels).
  delimeter: null, // If your group is not json, and is comma delimeted, you could set delimeter to ','.
  buffer: 0, // Useful for percentage based heights when they might not always be exactly the same (in pixels).
  columnThreshold: HAS_COMPUTED_STYLE ? 0.01 : 0.1, // Reading the width of elements isn't precise enough and can cause columns to jump between values.
  initialSort: null, // Shuffle can be initialized with a sort object. It is the same object given to the sort method.
  throttle: throttle, // By default, shuffle will throttle resize events. This can be changed or removed.
  throttleTime: 300, // How often shuffle can be called on resize (in milliseconds).
  sequentialFadeDelay: 150, // Delay between each item that fades in when adding items.
  supported: CAN_TRANSITION_TRANSFORMS // Whether to use transforms or absolute positioning.
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/jquery-shuffle/jquery.shuffle.modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/jquery-throttle-debounce/jquery-throttle-debounce.js"></script>

<section class="row section-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container top-padding-only">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 filter-options-list">
                    <div class="filter-options">
                        <h3 class="filter-options-title">Recent Projects</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-group="all">all</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-group="photography">photography</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-group="design">design</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-group="web">engineering</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="grid" class="row">
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-box" data-groups='["all", "photography"]'>
                <a href="#" class=""><img src="img/1.jpg" class="responsive-img" alt="">
                    <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-header">Portfolio Caption Header</div>
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-description">This is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this Portfolio</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-box" data-groups='["all", "design", "photography"]'>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/2.jpg" class="responsive-img" alt="">
                    <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-header">Portfolio Caption Header</div>
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-description">This is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this Portfolio</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-box" data-groups='["all", "photography"]'>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/3.jpg" class="responsive-img" alt="">
                    <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-header">Portfolio Caption Header</div>
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-description">This is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this Portfolio</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-box" data-groups='["all", "web", "design"]'>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/4.jpg" class="responsive-img" alt="">
                    <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-header">Portfolio Caption Header</div>
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-description">This is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this Portfolio</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-box" data-groups='["all", "design", "photography"]'>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/5.jpg" class="responsive-img" alt="">
                    <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-header">Portfolio Caption Header</div>
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-description">This is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this Portfolio</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-box" data-groups='["all", "photography"]'>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/6.jpg" class="responsive-img" alt="">
                    <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-header">Portfolio Caption Header</div>
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-description">This is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this Portfolio</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-box" data-groups='["all", "design", "web"]'>
                <a href="#" class=""><img src="img/1.jpg" class="responsive-img" alt="">
                    <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-header">Portfolio Caption Header</div>
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-description">This is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this Portfolio</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-box" data-groups='["all", "photography", "web"]'>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/2.jpg" class="responsive-img" alt="">
                    <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-header">Portfolio Caption Header</div>
                            <div class="four-portfolio-box-caption-content-description">This is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this PortfolioThis is a brief Description of this Portfolio</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <!-- sizer -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 shuffle_sizer"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: What is your console error? Errors are very helpful because they explain exactly what is wrong where!

Comment: the console error is : `Uncaught ReferenceError: HAS_COMPUTED_STYLE is not defined`. i have tried different values from integer to float to boolen... but i either get an error or a messed up layout

Comment: the shuffle.js doesnt say much about these options...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, HAS_COMPUTED_STYLE is a variable that you must have defined, and it looks like must be a boolean. Keeping in mind this, I don't know exactly what is the supposed style that you must have or not for your shuffle items, so I would put a simple "true" or "false" on that variable, whatever you want.

By other side, by see your Shuffle options object, I think you don't need this property. This should work:

```
Shuffle.options = {
  group: ALL_ITEMS,
  speed: 250,
  easing: 'ease-out',
  itemSelector: '.portfolio-box',
  sequentialFadeDelay: 150
};
```